# Google Play services out of date

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Создаю приложение с использованием firebase. При запуске на эмуляторе и попытки авторизации, получаю ошибку:

> Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found
>
> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8185470

А на эмуляторе выскакивает такое:

> Update Google Play services
>
> "AppName" won't run unless you update google play services

Все обновил как советовали на англоязичной части форума, но не помогло. Есть идеи как это исправить? Спасибо!

Это часть build.gradle(module)

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

А версия google play services на эмуляторе: 8.1.85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это проблема на девайсе/эмуляторе. Вам надо на самом девайсе/эмуляторе обновить сервисы гугла.

Переход на Genymotion решает проблему.

Comment: Я пробовал, но что то оно не обновляет, хотя может я не правильно понял суть. (я нашел в эмуляторе через поиск  google play services и пытался их так обновить, но не вышло. Или это нужно через андроид студию делать? Так зашел через  sdk manager и все обновил )

Comment: @Vcpp, попробуйте на реальном девайсе запустить, если заведётся - то проблема только в эмуляторе. Возможно, надо как то их хитро обновлять или переходить на Genymotion

Comment: @ValeraKvip, Что именно означает ваше `но не вышло`?